# Installation of GoodData.CN into AWS EKS

Tags: gooddata

I'm working on Installation GoodData.CN into our AWS EKS and I would be happy if you could help me with the installation process.
We have two separate AWS environments: a Dev/Test-stage and a Production stage. And we are using Redshift as a datasource as well, so it's necessary for us to have the possibility to work with it during development. However, I'm not able to use Enterprise License Key for Dev/Tests stage environment.
How can I install DEV/Test version (or a Community version) to AWS Kubernetes cluster?
Could you please give me an advice, how to install GoodData.CN as a Dev/Test version?
Is it possible to obtain a DEV/Test Licence Key for a Cloud-Native installation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

GoodData provides 3 various production ready editions - Free, Growth, Enterprise. In case of Free, you can get the license key upon registration of company email. There is no limitation on number of workspaces or registrations you can make.
For Growth and Enterprise this is handled individually. We can split the amount of workspaces you require between license keys you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks a lot like spam. Please read [answer] and [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).